# How to use XPATH to find a &nbsp; element in a HTMl document?

Tags: xpath

I have the following piece in a HTML document:

```
<div class="prompt input_prompt xh-highlight">
   <bdi class="">In</bdi>
   "&nbsp;[&nbsp;]:"
</div>
```

to find such occurrences (I mean the expression `[ ]:`) I tried the following ideas, but none worked:

```
//div/bdi/parent::*/text()="&nbsp;[&nbsp;]:"
//div/bdi/parent::*[contains(text(), " ")]
//div/bdi/parent::*[contains(text(), "&nbsp;")]
//div[contains(text(), "&nbsp;[&nbsp;]:")]
//div[contains(text(), "[ ]")]
//div[contains(text(), "[&nbsp;]")]
//div[contains(text(), "\u00a0]:")]
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

In XPath itself, the only way to represent the character xA0 in a string literal is as itself; so you can search for `//div[contains(., "[§]")]` where § is the character xA0. Of course, the disadvantage of this is that it's not obvious to your readers that the character in question is xA0 rather than an ordinary space.

XPath is often embedded in a host language, and the host language may well provide an alternative way to write this character. For example, if the host language is XML-based (e.g. XSLT) then you can write it as `&#xa0;`, while if it is Javascript, you can write it as `\u00a0`.

So the way to write the expression depends on your host language conventions.

Answer (score -1):

This works properly:

You search for all the elements that match the following `xpath` expression:

```
//div/bdi/parent::*[contains(text(), "]:")]
```

Then you loop over them and get their text, which you can easily compare in a logic and proper language, like python:

```
for element in elements:
    if '[ ]' in element.text:
        # some code
```

Comment: First, this `//div/bdi/parent::*` is the same as `//div[bdi]`. Second, it's better to use string value and not text nodes when you have mixed content (text and markup) because `contains(text()...)` really means _**"my first text node child contains..."**_. Finally, your answer doesn't cover your own question about the HTML entity `&nbsp;`. **See Dr. Kay answer**